# I installed the module, but still writes ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, pip

I installed Python using brew
I put the package like this pip install moderngl, as you can see in the screenshot it is there, but it still gives an error that it is not installed
[image]

Comment: Can you share the output of running `pip --version` and `python3 --version`

Comment: @MatteoZanoni pip 23.1.2 from /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/pip (python 3.11)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read this: [`ModernGL`](https://pypi.org/project/moderngl/)

Python is case-sensitive
It is `import moderngl` not `import ModernGL`
Like this works:

```
import math
```

This doesn't:

```
import MATH
```